# How to use JQuery Cropper plugin in Rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, crop

I found a crop image jquery plugin here https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper, and its samples is awsome.

But when I Integrated this plugin into my Rails app, I can only show the view but I can't submit the crop image form. Have anyone success use this cropper in Rails can show me an advice, many Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a lot of different scenarios. What you do not get?

```
cropper('getCropBoxData')
cropper('getCanvasData')
cropper('getImageData')
```

These methods give you the full information that the user has made to the image.